# Regarding rewrite engine

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

My htaccess file contains this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

this redirects all requests to my index.php page, which includes different files as required. That file brakes the url on the basis of `/` and gives output as an array.

`$request     = split("/", $request);`

If someone accesses `mywork/yash` , the query works fine as `$request[0]` becomes `yash`. But when I program for `$request[1]` it gives a `undefined offset` error.

I know this error arises when an array index which is undefined is accessed, but when `mywork/yash/` is acccessed, the error doesn't occur anymore !.

Can someone tell me the `.htaccess` rule to add a tail-ending slash after every request so as soon as the user types `mywork/yash` it gets converted to `mywork/yash/`.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The URL path will always begin with a `/`, so this doesn't make sense. You will never see `mywork/yash` as a path. It will always be `/mywork/yash`. Did you miss some important details in your question?

Comment: Where is `$request` coming from? And what does it contain? (It obviously doesn't contain `mywork/yash`.) `split()` is deprecated, you should be using `explode()` instead. The problem would seem to be with your processing of `$request`, not with a trailing slash - the two are unrelated?

Comment: it would contain `yash` . I want to add tail ending `/` to all links which user writes in the addressbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution !

made a function which solves like a breeze !

```
function redirect_to_unslashed($i)
```

`{`

`if(isset($_SESSION['request'][$i]))`

`{`

`if($_SESSION['request'][$i] == '')`

        `{
            navigate($_SESSION['request'][$i-1]);

        }`

`}`

`}`

this function actually redirects if the last slash contains an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

### The trailing slash

Using a rewrite rule to add the trailing slash is possible, but not purposeful since in that case, you can't redirect to `index.php` anymore.

If you really need that slash, you can still add it in your PHP script.

### Splitting the request

Assuming that `$request` is derived from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]`, you can split it at every occurence of `/` by writing

```
$parts = explode('/', $request);
```

For `mywork/yash` it would be

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "mywork"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "yash"
}
```

And for `mywork/yash/` it would be

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "mywork"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "yash"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

But when using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]`, you will always have a leading slash, which will result in the 1st element of `parts` being an empty string. You should be able to easily sort empty strings out, though.

Comment: my code is doing the same !